# s-replace filename in mode-line-format

Tags: mode-line-format

Trying to trim off some of the path in the filename in mode-line.
I now get `/share/Projects/<project_name>/...` trying to trim off the prefix `/share/Projects`

In my .emacs file:

```
(setq-default mode-line-format `(
 ,(propertize " Mode: " 'face 'bold)
 ,(propertize "%m " 'face '(:foreground "#fff"))
 ,(propertize " File: " 'face 'bold)
 ,(propertize (s-replace "/share/Projects" "" "%f") 'face '(:underline "red" :foreground "#fff" :height 1))
 ))
```

Not sure why it's not working, it still prints the full path, if I manually set the `"%f"` to `"/share/Projects/<project_name>"` it trims the string down as expected.

Comment: What is `s-replace`? What is `f` (where is it defined)? Have you tried just setting variable `mode-line-buffer-identification`?

Comment: Here is a link to s-replace docs [link](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-replace-old-new-s). f is the "buffer-file-name" [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/_0025_002dConstructs.html#g_t_0025_002dConstructs). The mode-line-buffer-id (%b), if thats what you meant, only shows the buffer name, not the filename/filepath.

Comment: Have you tried [`replace-regexp-in-string`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search-and-Replace.html) instead of `s-replace`?

Comment: Yes, same result, I'm starting to think maybe this aproach wont work. I guess maybe the actual variables are not populated at that point?

Comment: `%f` is the file name, not `f`.

Comment: Don't use string-manipulation functions on file names. Use file name-manipulation functions, such as `file-name-nondirectory`. They know about file names, including on different platforms.

Comment: I updated the question and changed `f` to `%f` for clarity, but they both give the same result, the full path. I will check out you sugestion, but the `file-name-nondirectory` wont work since i do want to keep the `<project_name>` directory and it's sub-directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `"/share/Projects"` with `""` in the string `"%f"` (a string which *clearly* does not contain `"/share/Projects"` at all) will result in the exact same unaltered string `"%f"` -- which will subsequently be processed as a mode line construct.

You will surely see this if you look at the value of `mode-line-format` after setting it.

You can try this construct instead:

```
(setq-default mode-line-format `(
  ...
  (:propertize (:eval (s-replace "/share/Projects" "" buffer-file-name))
               face (:underline "red" :foreground "#fff" :height 1))
  ...))
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however your example sets all model-lines to the .emacs file's buffer-file-name, so they now all say `~/.emacs`

Comment: Also worth noteing that `(s-replace "/share/Projects" "" f)`, so using `f` instead of `"%f"`, also prints the full path.

Comment: @ladrua Don't *unquote* any part of the code I suggested.  Your original code used `,(propertize ...)` -- don't do that here!

Comment: You are absolutely right, works like a charm! One thing, I had to change `'face` to just `face` for the styling to work. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oops, very true; a bad copy/paste on my part, sorry.  Glad you got it working.  The list value of the `face` property shouldn't be quoted either, but it looks like that still works regardless.  I've updated the answer accordingly.